# How to pass a variable from $scope into a directive, and reverse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-directive

I am currently trying to implement a directive that should make some DOM elements blink. For that, I am using `$timeout` to set visibility of the element to either visible or hidden. My problem is that if in the `$timeout` call I hard-code a value (say '500') everything runs smoothly. But if I try to pass this parameter thanks to a variable, I get the element blinking extremely fast, as if no parameter was entered (default value is '0').

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-key"><span class="blink" blinkSpeed='500'>Q</span></button>
{{displayBlinkSpeed}}
```

**JS**

```
.directive('blink',function($timeout){
return{
    restrict:'ACE',
    transclude: true,
    scope:{
        blinkSpeed: '='
    },
    link: function(scope,element,attrs){
        function showElement(){             
            var speed = parseInt(scope.blinkSpeed);
            element.css("visibility","visible");
            $timeout(hideElement,speed);
            scope.displayBlinkSpeed = speed;
        }

        function hideElement(){
            var speed = parseInt(scope.blinkSpeed);
            element.css("visibility","hidden");
            $timeout(showElement,speed);
            scope.displayBlinkSpeed = speed;
        }

        showElement();
    },
    template: '<span ng-transclude></span>',
    replace: true
    };
});
```

Also, I forgot to mention that `{{displayBlinkSpeed}}` in the HTML is not showing anything either.
My guess would be that my directive is not able to communicate (receive/send) information to the DOM. Unfortunately, I have not found a way to make it work. Have I missed/misunderstood something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, `{{displayBlinkSpeed}}` would not show anything, since `displayBlinkSpeed` is only defined within the isolate scope of the directive - it's `undefined` outside of it.

And as for `blinkSpeed` - when you bind to an attribute, Angular normalizes the attribute name, so `scope: {blinkSpeed: "="}` is bound to `blink-speed="500"` attribute (not `blinkSpeed="500"` attribute). Without it, `$scope.blinkSpeed === undefined`, and `parseInt(undefined) === NaN`, which results in flickering.

Change the HTML to:

```
<span class="blink" blink-speed='500'>Q</span>
```

**Somewhat off-topic:**

**1:** You don't need to do `parseInt(scope.blinkSpeed)` since `"="` would correctly resolve to an integer. So, the following would work just as well:

```
$timeout(hideElement, $scope.blinkSpeed);
```

**2:** since you don't intend to modify the blink speed within the directive, it is wasteful to do two-way binding with `"="` - instead use one-way binding to an expression with `"&"`:

```
scope: {
  blinkSpeed: "&",
},
link: function(scope){
  var speed = scope.blinkSpeed();
  $timeout(hideElement, speed);
}
```